# Macro or equivalent in reStructuredText?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I have a `<form>` like this all the times.

```
.. raw:: html

    <form action="txmt://open/?url=file:///Users/smcho/smcho/works/prgtask/ni/gtest_boost_options/readme.txt">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
    </form>
```

Is there any macro or equivalent in reStructuredText so that I can get the same result, for example?

```
.. form :: /Users/smcho/smcho/works/prgtask/ni/gtest_boost_options/readme.txt
```

Comment: Not for this question but for math then MathJax's `\newcommand` can be used as usual. Not usable in this case though. // Defining new role is also an option and does not require taking a newline: https://web.archive.org/web/20221206221128/https://doughellmann.com/posts/defining-custom-roles-in-sphinx/ // https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html

Comment: There's also substitution: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement your own "form" directive in python. For instructions on how to do that, see
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-directives.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any template engine to generate your restructured text, and that gives you macros, loops, and much more. It will require some effort at the beginning, but it should not be terribly hard.